# calculate time from GMT time and user time zone

Tags: php, mysql

I have one mysql DB saving time for every record with GMT time for every user. like

```
id user_id   date_added
1  1        2016-06-08 12:22:19
2  2        2016-06-08 11:22:14
3  4        2016-06-08 11:02:09
4  1        2016-06-08 10:12:11
```

I also have table saved timezone for each user like

```
id  user_name   timezone
1   user1       Pacific/Midway
2   user2       Asia/Dubai
```

now i want to calculate real time for user record using above time zone in PHP.

i tried many examples but not working cause some zone are + and some are -

Thanks

Comment: Just use `datetime + timezoneValue`

Comment: @juergen d thanks for reply but did you see timezonevalue its text... i try but its not working

Comment: Of course you have to get the INT values for those timezone names first.

Comment: It can help you http://php.net/manual/en/function.timezone-offset-get.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that all dates are stored in UTC date format, you need to convert the timezone to get the local time for each user.

Example:

```
// default timezone is UTC
$date = new DateTime('2016-06-08 12:22:19', new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
var_dump($date->format('Y-m-d H:i:sP'));

// convert timezone to Asia/Dubai +4 UTC
$date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Asia/Dubai'));
var_dump($date->format('Y-m-d H:i:sP'));
```

The output will be

```
   string '2016-06-08 12:22:19+00:00' (length=25) 
   string '2016-06-08 16:22:19+04:00' (length=25)
```

To get rid of `+00` and `+04` change the format by removing `P`

```
$date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
$date = new DateTime('2016-09-18 16:17:34', new DateTimeZone('Asia/Dhaka'));

// datetime for the timezone
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Answer (score -1):

Example:

```
// date from db
$date_string = '2016-06-08 11:22:14';

// create timezone
$dateTimeZone = new DateTimeZone('Asia/Dubai');

// create date time for timezone
$dateTimeLocale = new DateTime( $date_string, $dateTimeZone );
```